# Дистанционное обучение — очное обучение?

Tags: лексика

Как можно назвать тип обучения, при котором студенты посещают учебное заведение и его аудитории, лекции проходят очно? Очное обучение противопоставлено заочному (предполагает необходимость регулярных посещений), поэтому, вероятно, некорректно противопоставлять его дистанционному.

Answer (score 1):

В России нет, с юридической точки зрения, дистанционного обучения как третьего вида. Дистанционное считается формой очного. При этом в различных документах встречается как противопоставление очного дистанционному, так и объединение (в общий термин "очно-дистанционное обучение").

С точки же зрения русского языка, предполагаю, не будет ошибкой противопоставлять каждый вид обучения двум другим.